# String throwing exception

Tags: c++, exception, constructor

I have the following code with two functions which should throw exceptions when condition is satisfied. Unfortunately the second one with string seems not working and I don't have a clue whats wrong

```
#include "iostream"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "string"
using namespace std;
 
struct P
{
    int first;
    string second;
};
 
void T(P b)
{ if (b.first==0)
throw (b.first);
};
 
void U(P b)
{ if (b.second == "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9" )
throw (b.second);
};
 
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
P x;
cin>>x.first;
cin>>x.second;
 
try
    {  
        P x;
        T(x);
    }
    catch (int exception)
    {
        std::cout << exception;
    }
 
    try{
        U(x);
    }
    catch (const char* exception)
    {
        std::cout << "\n" << exception;
    }
 
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

I have the following input:

```
0
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

and the output:

```
0
```

and I want to get:

```
0
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

How can I change char for string output?

Comment: What specifically is wrong with the code? What input did you give? Note that you are catching `const char*`, but you are throwing `std::string`. I'm not sure if this is supposed to work.

Comment: You are throwing a `std::string` but you are trying to catch a `const char*`

Comment: @SimonKraemer , @churill , yes, I actually thought about that but I don't know the walk around for string as `string exception` is not correct

Comment: `P x; T(x);` is passing a different `x` to `T` than the one you initialized with `std::cin`. In `T` you start with `b.first==0` but that `first` member is uninitialized, meaning it has Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, I removed the duplicate `P x;` declaration but the problem remains. I don't get why x is different and how first is uninitialized

Comment: @Michael The syntax `type name;` declares a new object. If you declare an object in an inner scope that has the same name as an object in an outer scope, the inner one hides the outer one until the end of that inner scope.

Comment: Next problem `std::cin >> x;` will stop reading at the first white space. You need to use `std::getline` to read a whole line. I also suggest to learn how to use a debugger to investigate the state of your program at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know what you are trying to experiment, but despite being allowed by the language, throwing objects that are not instances of (subclasses of) `std::exception` should be avoided.

That being said you have a bunch of inconsistencies in your code.

First `cin >> x.second;` will stop **at the first blank character**. So in your example you have only `"1,"` in `x.second`, so you test fails and you code does not throw anything.

You should ignore the newline left by `cin >> x.first` and use `getline` to read a full line include spaces:

```
P x;
cin >> x.first;
cin.ignore();
std::getline(cin, x.second);
```

The first `try` block invokes UB, because you are declaring a **new** `x` in that block that will hide the one you have just read. It should be:

```
try
{
    //P x;  // do not hide x from the enclosing function!
    T(x);
}
```

Finaly, and even it is not an error you should always catch non trivial object by const reference to avoid a copy. Remember that exceptions are expected to be raised in abnormal conditions, and when memory becomes scarce you should avoid copy. But you **must** catch the exact same object that was thrown. So the second `catch` should be:

```
catch (std::string exception)
{
    std::cout << "\n" << exception;
}
```

or better (avoid a copy):

```
catch (const std::string& exception)
{
    std::cout << "\n" << exception;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your full review, the one with `getline` was quite helpful!
I guess that was the issue I was looking for